# execCommand h1 style only selected text

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on custom textarea with highlighting options.
Now added h1-h4 & bold options.

**Problem:**

When I select the text and click on Heading1 button it style the whole row not selected text. When I click on Bold button it style only selected text.

I want to apply h1-h4 style only for selected text instead of whole row.

**Here is my code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Comment</h2>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <button data-command="h1" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Heading1</button>
        <button data-command="h2" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Heading2</button>
        <button data-command="h3" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Heading3</button>
        <button data-command="h4" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Heading4</button>
        <button data-command="bold" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Bold</button>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body" contenteditable>Sample comment</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $(".btn").click(function() {
      var command = $(this).data("command");
      if (command == 'h1' || command == 'h2' || command == 'h3' || command == 'h4')
        document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, '<' + command + '>');
      else
        document.execCommand(command);
    })
  })
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I liked your question. I was not aware of this api. But please next time use ES6(it is everywhere now) and brackets for block expressions.

So from docs

> Adds an HTML block-level element around the **line** containing the current selection, replacing the block element containing the line if one exists (in Firefox,  is the exception — it will wrap any containing block element). Requires a tag-name string as a value argument. Virtually all block-level elements can be used.

But you can use `insertHTML` command.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html />
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Comment</h2>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <button data-command="h1" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
            Heading1
          </button>
          <button data-command="h2" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
            Heading2
          </button>
          <button data-command="h3" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
            Heading3
          </button>
          <button data-command="h4" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
            Heading4
          </button>
          <button data-command="bold" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
            Bold
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body" contenteditable>Sample comment</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $(".btn").click(function() {
        var command = $(this).data("command");
        if (
          command == "h1" ||
          command == "h2" ||
          command == "h3" ||
          command == "h4"
        ) {
          const selection = window.getSelection();
          document.execCommand(
            "insertHTML",
            false,
            `<${command}>${selection}</${command}>`
          );
        } else {
          document.execCommand(command);
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Also do not forget to serialize you content.

Comment: thank you so much it is working, but goes to next line. should I use inline block css for h1 command

Comment: Yes, if you want on the same line because headings are `block` by default. There might be some issues too, but I hope you got the concept.

Comment: Now it is working but due to insertHtml it is removing existing formatting also, suppose italic text is there and I want to apply h2 style for that, it remove italic style and apply only h2

Comment: That I was talking about. I just gave the basic concept, how to do it